# Speech recognition shows Error In Python (Positional Argument Error)

Tags: python, function, speech-recognition, pyttsx3

Python gives a error when I run this code and I've checked it number of times. The source here is the Microphone, but yet it keeps on asking a value for the 'source'. What should I do. What parameter should I pass to the 'source'?

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
#Required Modules

engine = pyttsx3.init()
r = sr.Recognizer
#Initializes variable (Avoiding Time Delay)

def Speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()
#Defining the function Speak() for Audio Output

def Listen():
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise
        print("Listening")
        voice = r.listen(source)
        print("Done Listening")
        a = r.recognize_google(voice)
        a = a.lower()
        print("You asked - "+a)    
#Defining the function Listen() for Audio Input (INTERNET REQUIRED)

while True:    
    Speak("Ask Me Some Questions")
    #Speaks

    Listen()
    #Listens

    try:
        if a == "how are you":
            print("I'm Fine Sir")
            Speak("I'm Fine Sir") 
    #Tries to do the program without error
    
    except:
        print("Error Occured!!!")
    #If error occured, this will be the Output                   

#Looped
```

This Code Gives an error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Vishal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Python Projects\Speech.py", line 29, in <module>
    Listen()
  File "c:\Users\Vishal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Python Projects\Speech.py", line 18, in Listen
    voice = r.listen(source)
TypeError: listen() missing 1 required positional argument: 'source'
```

What is actaully the error and how to solve it? (I'm a beginner in python, so go easy on me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated code

1.You have to go through documentation always first there should be sr.Recognizer()

2.and if you are creating method then for interaction you should return value

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
#Required Modules

engine = pyttsx3.init()
r = sr.Recognizer()
#Initializes variable (Avoiding Time Delay)

def Speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()
#Defining the function Speak() for Audio Output

def Listen():
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        print("Listening")
        voice = r.listen(source)
        print("Done Listening")
        a = r.recognize_google(voice)
        a = a.lower()
        print("You asked - "+a)   
        return a
#Defining the function Listen() for Audio Input (INTERNET REQUIRED)

while True:    
    Speak("Ask Me Some Questions")
    #Speaks

    a=Listen()
    #Listens

    try:
        if a == "how are you":
            print("I'm Fine Sir")
            Speak("I'm Fine Sir") 
    #Tries to do the program without error
    
    except:
        print(a)
        print("Error Occured!!!")
    #If error occured, this will be the Output                   

#Looped
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that really helped